# Numerical Minimization not working as it should

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Thanks for the help in advance!
I have setup a module intending it to work as a function for minimization. The module works flawlessly for things such as plotting, but when I try to use a minimization algorythm on it i get errors from the Eigenvalues function used in the module (Which again, works good for plots). Any idea on what might be happening?

```
NSolve[{SigmasWithQR[10, 2, 0.7, x, 0.4, y, 30][[1]] = 
SigmasWithQR[10, 2, 0.7, x, 0.4, y, 30][[2]] && 
SigmasWithQR[10, 2, 0.7, x, 0.4, y, 30][[2]] = 
SigmasWithQR[10, 2, 0.7, x, 0.4, y, 30][[3]]}, {x, y}]
```

Using minimize on another module defined as the difference between the three quantities i am trying to equate results in the exact same output.

(I am sorry, i am new here and dont really know how to format the error. I know I am not providing a minimal functioning example, but since I dont know what might be malfunctioning, I have no idea on how to narrow it down.)
Error: 
"Unable to find all roots of the characteristic polynomial"

Comment: Without code, no one will be able to answer your question unfortunately (in a way other than guessing).

Comment: Also, do you really have `=` instead of `==` in your code, or was this just a typo in the question?

Comment: "Unable to find all roots of the characteristic polynomial" indicates that it is related to the way you produce the eigenvalues...